# C# HttpClient PostAsync 403 forbidden with SSL

Tags: c#, visual-studio

since we switch to a server with SSL when i make a POST i always recieve a 403 forbidden error, but if i use WebClient it works fine, anyway i still want to make it work with HttpClient because i would have to change a lot of code and also there is a call that post a file using MultipartFormDataContent and i can´t do that with WebClient, in Webclient i have the option to POST data or Upload a file but i need to POST data and the file in one call.

here is a example of the HttpClient and the WebClient calls

HttpClient (403 forbidden error)

```
 private async void Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Apic = CryptoEngine.DecryptAPI(Apic);
        if (API())
        {
            using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                if (EmailText.Text.Contains("@") && EmailText.Text.Contains("."))
                {
                    content.Add(new StringContent(EmailText.Text), "\"email\"");
                }
                else
                {
                    content.Add(new StringContent(EmailText.Text), "\"username\"");
                }

                content.Add(new StringContent(PasswordText.Password), "\"password\"");
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.ParseAdd("application/json");
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36");
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("appName", "CloudMetaPrinter");
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("latitude", Apic.Latitude);
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("longitude", Apic.Longitude);
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("hostname", Apic.IP);
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("hostType", "PC");
                    var httpResponse = httpClient.PostAsync(url + "/" + api + "/auth/login", content);
                    responseContent = await httpResponse.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Result result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(responseContent);
```

WebClient (works fine)

```
private void Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Apic = CryptoEngine.DecryptAPI(Apic);
        if (API())
        {
            string data;
            if (EmailText.Text.Contains("@"))
            {
                data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                {
                    email = EmailText.Text,
                    password = PasswordText.Password
                });
            }
            else
            {
                data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                {
                    username = EmailText.Text,
                    password = PasswordText.Password
                });
            }
            using (var httpClient = new WebClient { UseDefaultCredentials = true })
            {
                httpClient.Headers.Add("appName", "CloudMetaPrinter");
                httpClient.Headers.Add("latitude", Apic.Latitude);
                httpClient.Headers.Add("longitude", Apic.Longitude);
                httpClient.Headers.Add("hostname", Apic.IP);
                httpClient.Headers.Add("hostType", "PC");
                httpClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                var httpResponse = httpClient.UploadData(url + "/" + api + "/auth/login", "POST", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
                var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(httpResponse);
                Result result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(str);
```

i tried to make changes in the header, UseDefaultCredentials = true, etc and nothing works.

Edit: im using .net core 3.0
Edit2: The GetAsync with HttpClient works fine, the problem is only with PostAsync.

Ok so i tried to compare with fiddler and change some thing so the httpclient call is more like the webclient but still im getting the 403
Left is WebClient and right is HttpClient
[Compare image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jtyds.png)

Comment: Regardless of the code, you could easily use fiddler to see what is different about the 2 methods when posting to the server, to help you solve future issues

Comment: You're using different credentials in each case. With WebClient, you're using Windows Authentication. With HttpClient,*no authentication at all*. You aren't even passing a Basic Authentication header. Change the HttpClient code to use Windows Authentication too

Comment: The two snippets are very different too - the first posts a form,  the second sends a JSON string. Why do you expect them to behave the same?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos before using the SSL server the HttpClient worked so i guess is because Windows Authentication, but im having trouble finding information on how to change the HttpClient to use Windows Authentication

Comment: @mortb No, in that anwser they end up using WebClient, i need to use HttpClient.

Comment: SSL has no effect. Your code in the two snippets is completely different. You aren't using *any* credentials with HttpClient, effectively making an anonymous call. The rest of the call is completely different too. With WebClient, you're making a POST (that's what UploadData does) with a JSON string. With HttpClient you're posting a form

Comment: @TheGeneral I do the test with fiddler and made some changes to make it look as similar as possible but I still have some differences, can you please check the image I put on the last edit and tell me what I'm missing? I've tried to search but I found nothing

Answer (score 11):

**[Solution]**
Add the below header section

Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");

Comment: Surprisingly, this worked for me. It appears that some servers will reject a call without a user-agent defined. HttpClient does not provide a default value. `request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Other");`

Comment: @ChrisJensen Yes. That server's network side applied for a security role as a User Agent required. That is why getting a Forbidden ERROR

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a `HttpClienthandler` object into the constructor of the `HttpClient`. The `UseDefaultCredentials` property has been moved to `HttpClienthandler`

Example:

```
   using(var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
   {
      handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

      using(var client = new HttpClient(handler))
      {

         var response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.contoso.com/");
         response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

         var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   }
```

(Please note that it might be inefficient to `Dispose()` the `HttpClient` frequently, it is better to reuse it.)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: I already try that and i still get the 403 forbidden, at least with post, with get I don't set nothing and it works

Comment: It is hard to compare the two examples in your question. You post `MultipartFormDataContent` in your `HttpClient` example and a json string in your `WebClient` example, so they are doing different things. Have you tried posting Json with `HttpClient`?

Comment: I know that is different, but if I use the call without the SSL server bot ways works, is only with the SSL, please check the image of the comparison that I made in fiddler, I made a few changes so bot calls are the most likely as possible but I still have some minimum differences that I don't know how to change it

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you do not have a proxy blocking the call. Either do not use the proxy or make sure that you have the right address and port configured.  Using the handler in mortb’s example:

```
using (var handler=new HttpHandler())
{
     handler.UseProxy=false;
     var client=new HttpClient(handler);
     var result=await client.PostAsync(url);
     //… retrieve the content
}
```